# Hive Contiguous Date Ranges

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am using Hive and I would like to take a table with a historical list of customers, subscription events, and subscription types and summarize by contiguous runs of subscription types for each customer.

Example Input (db.cust_hist):

```
customer_id |     eff_dt |     exp_dt | sub_cd | sub_type
---------------------------------------------------------
          1 | 02/01/2015 | 03/01/2015 | active | A
          1 | 03/01/2015 | 04/01/2015 | active | A
          1 | 03/15/2015 | 12/31/9999 | cancel | A
          1 | 04/01/2015 | 05/01/2015 | active | A
          1 | 05/01/2015 | 06/01/2015 | active | A
          1 | 02/01/2015 | 03/01/2015 | active | B
          1 | 03/01/2015 | 04/01/2015 | active | B
```

The sub_cd in this case refers to the type of event that is effective over the date range for that row. For example, the user canceled their A subscription type on 3/15 and resumed on 4/01.

The output I'm trying to get looks like this (db.cust_snapshot):

```
customer_id |     eff_dt |     exp_dt | sub_type
------------------------------------------------
          1 | 02/01/2015 | 03/15/2015 | A
          1 | 04/01/2015 | 06/01/2015 | A
          1 | 02/01/2015 | 04/01/2015 | B
```

and reflects the gap in coverage.

From what I have read in this [link from BetterAtOracle (specific to SQL)](http://betteratoracle.com/posts/35-collapsing-continuous-ranges-into-single-rows) which does a very good job of laying things out, I need to use row numbers and a lagging window, but I can't seem to apply it to my situation in Hive (perhaps because of the 12/31/9999 notation/subscription code?)

I tried:

```
SELECT customer_id
, eff_dt
, exp_dt
, sub_cd
, sub_type
, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(TO_DATE(eff_dt), TO_DATE(lag(exp_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, sub_type ORDER BY eff_dt)) <=1 THEN NULL
       ELSE row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id, sub_type ORDER BY eff_dt)
       END) as grp
FROM db.cust_hist
ORDER BY TO_DATE(eff_dt)
```

As you can see, I haven't applied the subscription event code. This sort of gets me there as I can start to see different groups based on subscription type, but I feel like I'm stuck from here on out.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Before this task, I never understood the true power of ranks, rows, lag, and other window functions!

Comment: Can't you add where condition to filter out cancelled ones.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the cancellation entries if a subscription was terminated early. There are essentially two ways a subscription can end: by hitting the expiration date or by a cancellation which is effective on some intermediate date until the "end of time."

Comment: `12/31/9999` notation is easy to change to YYYYMMDD using substr+concat

Comment: Not sure I see what you're getting at. The format of the date is not the issue. I think the main issue is the fact that cancellation events and effective events are the same format in each row except for a "code" that signifies whether that row is canceling existing subscriptions or defining new subscriptions.